# How to add two values from two different list

Tags: python, list, sum, zip

EDIT : I realize something. When I read the file, I'm reading not only the values but the labels before !

I got an issue with some list, I'm reading a file and the result is put in datalist. Then I try to add to these values, the value from an other list. So now I have :

```
datalist = [['first','second','third','fourth','fifth'],[1,2,3,4,5]]
newData_list = [0,1,1,0,2]
```

I want :     datalist= [1,3,4,4,7]  I was doing this :

```
datalist= [some1, some2, some3]
newData_list=[thing1, thing2, thing3]
datalist = [sum(x) for x in zip(datalist, newData_list)]
#and already try these
#datalit = sum([datalist,newData_list], axis=0)
#datalist = map(sum, zip(datalist, newData_list))
#datalist=[x + y for x, y in zip(datalist, newData_list)]*
```

Depending on which line I use I got these errors :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

I'm using csv.reader to get the value from the file. The content is save in datalist as a list. How can I manipulate the second element of datalist ( one with numbers) , I guess I have to convert list type to integer and it will works but how ? Thanks !

Comment: I guess your lists must contain nested lists and integers, but you'll need to show us your actual lists do be sure

Comment: Your list is initialized as: `new_Data_list ` but you are using `newData_list `. Is that a typo or actual issue?

Comment: Just typo, sorry I will edit this

Comment: if your datalist and newData_list are int  then datalist = [sum(x) for x in zip(datalist, newData_list)] will work fine but type error will come when datalist or newData_list doest contain int element instead 1 of item is list not int

Comment: Ok you right, when I read the register, I save the content in list type, I didn't notice this because it was made by someone else. I try to cast datalist but I supposed not with the right method because it doesn't work. Did I have to cast it when I call zip ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with map and zip:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
map(lambda (x,y): x+y,zip(a,b))
```

output:

```
[5, 7, 9]
```

Hmm I also tried your code from above it works normal.
So your problem should be the value in the lists. They aren't integer but it looks like more that they are lists.

Comment: I will try and tell you. The thing is, I wanted to be sure that I got integer in my list so I made a type(thing1) and type(some1) and I got type int so..

Comment: I still got an error TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Comment: can you print the two lists and show me the output?

Comment: I'm doing this for datalist : 

    datalist = list(reader)#Save file content as a list Where reader is : reader = csv.reader(csvreadfile, delimiter=',') I check and the data in newData_list are int The question is now, how do I cast data in datalist to get an integer

Answer (score 0):

I'm just doing this and it seems to work :

```
datalist[1] = map(int, datalist[1])
```